# Okhttp:get the value of a variable assigned inside OnResponse

Tags: android, okhttp

I assigned a variable inside OnResponse，but it seems unable to get its value outside OnResponse, how can I get its value? Here is my code below.

```
    public class LoginMethods {
        public String title, str;

        public String Login(String URL, String account, String password, String verifycode){
            FormBody formbody =  new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("TextBox2",password)
                    .add("txtSecretCode",verifycode)
                    .add("txtUserName",account)
                    .build();
            Request request=new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(formbody)
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client2 = new OkHttpClient();

            client2.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    str = response.body().string();
                }
            });

            Document doc=Jsoup.parse(str);
            title = doc.select("title").first().text();
            return title;
        }
    }
```

Here are part of the Logcat below：

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String input must not be null
        at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:26)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:26)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:42)
        at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:52)
        at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:89)
        at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:58)
```

Comment: Add your log file with the error portion to make it easy for others to assess your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're running the calls asynchronously. This means that `Jsoup.parse(str);` will most likely happen before the call finished and assigned a value to `str`.

You need to for example move the code inside `onResponse` and provide a callback for your title. Here's an example:

```
interface OnTitleReceivedListener {
   void onTitleReceived(String title);
}

public class LoginMethods {
    public void Login(String URL, String account, String password, String verifycode, OnTitleReceivedListener listener){
        FormBody formbody =  new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("TextBox2",password)
                .add("txtSecretCode",verifycode)
                .add("txtUserName",account)
                .build();
        Request request=new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formbody)
                .build();
        OkHttpClient client2 = new OkHttpClient();

        client2.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                response.body().string();
                Document doc=Jsoup.parse(str);
                listener.onTitleReceived(doc.select("title").first().text());
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, whoever calls `Login` will have to pass an interface that will receive the title when it's ready, meaning when you actually got it from the network.

The key concept here is that things are and should be asynchronous when it comes to network requests/responses and callbacks are one way of doing this.

The are other methods like reactive streams that have the possibility to offload the work to another thread.

**edit**:

Function can then be called with a lambda:

```
new LoginMethods.Login("url", "account", "pwd", "verify code", (title) -> System.out.println(title));
```

If you don't have lambdas then you can always create an anonymous class:

```
new LoginMethods.Login("url", "account", "pwd", "verify code", new OnTitleReceivedListener() {
  public void onTitleReceived(String title){
        System.out.println(title);
   }
 });
```

Just like you did for the Retrofit callbacks.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of calling Login?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but in short it's exactly how you did it for the Retrofit callbacks